# Benefits of killing anything?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Does a hero killing a lane minion give more xp than if it were to just die near a hero?

Is there anyway to even see the xp? when something dies I just see +Xp and that's it.

Comment: I don't *think* it makes a difference, but I haven't tested to confirm.  Part of the draw of HotS is that it removes a lot of the meta game that other MOBAs have that don't really make much sense in context.  Why should it matter *who* kills a minion, as long as they die?  Why do they carry so much gold?  Why doesn't your side's merchant just give you the items so you can save them from the enemy team instead of making you earn them?  For that matter, why didn't you bring freaking equipment?  How do a helicopter, a snake, and a yeti all wear the same pair of boots?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XP is global and finite. There is no difference or benefit from killing a minion vs. standing next to a dying minion.

Importantly, having multiple heroes together has no effect on XP gain -- in fact, it might even be a net negative if there are enemy minions dying elsewhere on the map *not* near a hero. (Spread to all lanes to maximize XP gain).

One minor caveat is that hero-based minion kills always give XP to the hero, even if they are not nearby (for instance, Asmodan's Q).

Comment: "Net negative" meaining IF you can, always have one hero in a lane gaining exp.

Comment: do you get experience if abathur's monstrosity was standing next to a dying minion?

Comment: Out of interest what do you mean by "finite" in this context? I am reading it as "not infinite" which doesn't seem right (I mean its true but not a useful observation).

Comment: @Chris Regardless of how many allied heroes are adjacent to a dying minion, it will reward the same amount of XP. This is different from a game like League of Legends, where both heroes would get a summed value greater than if there had been only one there.